# java-cassnadra object Frozen annotation for address map<text, frozen<list<frozen<address>>>>,

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to insert data into Cassandra(2.1.9)
My Java object has a map of a list of UDT. On running the code I am getting error regarding @Frozen annotation. I am using DataStax(2.1.9) Library.
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/index.html?com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/FrozenValue.html

```
create table user{
        name text,
        addresses map<text, frozen<list<frozen<address>>>>,
}
```

My Java Class

```
public class User{
    private String name;
    @FrozenValue
    private Map<String, List<AddressUDT>> addresses;
}
```

But I am getting following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while checking frozen types on field addresses of entity com.dante.data.model.User: expected AddressUDT to be frozen but was not frozen
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationChecks.validateAnnotations(AnnotationChecks.java:73) ~[cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.parseEntity(AnnotationParser.java:81) ~[cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getMapper(MappingManager.java:148) ~[cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.mapper(MappingManager.java:105) ~[cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.dante.data.migration.dao.UserMigrationDao.insertUsersToCassandra(UserMigrationDao.java:389) ~[UserMigrationDao.class:na]
    at com.dante.data.migration.service.impl.UserMigration.insertUsersToCassandra(UserMigration.java:32) ~[UserMigration.class:na]
    at com.dante.data.migration.controller.DataMigrationController.migrateUserDetails(DataMigrationController.java:93) ~[DataMigrationController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Please suggest the resolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Frozen("map<text, frozen<list<frozen<AddressUDT>>>>")
private Map<String, List<AddressUDT>> addresses;
```

Comment: How to extract addresses map<text, frozen<list<frozen<address>>>> to custom type in cql of cassandra?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but the docs state that @FrozenValue in your case is short for:

`@Frozen("map<text, frozen<list<address>>>")`

So the address defined as frozen from your create table statement doens't match that. Try to either remove the frozen from address or use the above annotation including the additional frozen for address.

Comment: Yes, `@Frozen` with a text string is the way to solve this. Note that these checks will likely be disabled in the next 2.1 version (see [JAVA-843](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-843) for more details).