# Create user type with list<text> in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table to create in cassandra with custom type.
From java project, I have this class :

```
public class Product {

    @Column(value = "tags")
    private List<String> tags;

    @Column(value = "price")
    private double price;
}
```

I want to create a user-type in cassandra with this class :

```
CREATE TYPE quangkeyspace.student (
  tags list<text>,
  price floats
);
```

But it has error when execute : `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="A user type cannot contain non-frozen UDTs"`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Cassandra version, you may be required to define your UDT as [frozen](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Frozen.html). This practically means that the field is immutable and that cassandra treats the field as a blob, preventing the modification of different fields inside of the type.

Also, keep in mind that Partition keys must always be frozen due to how tokens are hashed from the value of the key.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762981/java-cassnadra-object-frozen-annotation-for-address-maptext-frozenlistfrozen) might be doing what you want.